# Book recommendation for transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Can I please get recommendations for books/notes on transformations? The topics covered should be

1. Affine transformations
2. Projective transformations
3. Transformations in Euclidean space

etc

A strong linear algebra approach would be preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Artin's *Geometric Algebra*](http://books.google.com/books?id=R99WmOSpn88C&printsec=frontcover&dq=artin+geometric+algebra&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5WeQU8KzDIbE8AGi2IDgCA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=artin%20geometric%20algebra&f=false) and [Kaplansky's *Linear algebra and geometry*](http://books.google.com/books?id=nUcUYHrYJtgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=kaplansky+linear+algebra+geometry&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AGiQU5CKEeGT8AHXyYH4CA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kaplansky%20linear%20algebra%20geometry&f=false)

Both of them, especially read together, do a good job of integrating transformational geometry with linear algebra.